# Is the Social Security retirement benefit calculation based on the last 40 quarters, or overall?

Tags: united-states, retirement, calculation, social-security

Are Social Security payouts based on the last 40 quarters, or overall earnings? That is:

If the last 40 quarters of my working career are lower than these past 40 quarters worth, how does this affect Social Security payouts? (If it's around when I retire.)

Comment: Related question: [Help required on estimating SSA benefit amounts](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19193/help-required-on-estimating-ssa-benefit-amounts).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Social Security payments for retirement are based on 35 years of indexed earnings. If you have less than 35 years of earnings, then your record will have zeros. If you have more than 35 years, the lowest indexed amounts will be dropped. If someone is receiving benefits but is also working, then the benefits are re-calculated (and thus increased) if one of the 35 previous "highest" years can be replaced with a newer "top-35" year. (There is a time-delay in this recalculation; it does not happen as soon as the year ends)

The 40 Quarters requirement is the minimum number of quarters to be *eligible* for retirement benefits. Once you reach 40 Quarters, the top 35 years' earnings calculation is used.

The Social Security Administration even has a table ([Benefit Calculation Examples for Workers Retiring in 2015](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/progdata/retirebenefit1.html)) to explain this. The SSA also indexes your earnings so that it reflects changes in the standard of living. You can see the [indexing factors](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/COLA/awifactors.html).

You can use, and should use the [My Social Security Account](http://www.ssa.gov/myaccount/) to check your own estimates and to:

> - Keep track of your earnings and verify them every year;
> - Get an estimate of your future benefits if you are still working;
> - Get a letter with proof of your benefits if you currently receive them; and
> - Manage your benefits

Comment: Additional information: The Social Security benefits are based on a _weighted_ sum of the highest 35 years of earnings. If someone is receiving benefits but is also working, then the benefits are _re-calculated_ (and thus increased) if one of the 35 previous "highest" years can be replaced with a newer "top-35" year. (There is a time-delay in this recalculation; it does not happen as soon as the year ends).

Comment: So, if the current year can replace the lowest on the 35/high list it will do it, in effect, one will always have a currest 'high 35' running list. I got that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is possible fro somebody nearing Full retirement age can get a boost in the benefit because that last year of work replaces an year early in their career, maybe even one where they only worked part time.

Comment: You might edit in - the 40 quarters is the minimum to qualify for benefits. Once that's reached, your 35 year average is how the actual benefit is calculated.

Comment: I added the changes requested

Comment: A couple of special quirks that will be encountered by only a few readers here. Suppose that you are getting a pension from money that you never paid SS tax on (Employees of States that have _opted out_ of Social Security are usually those in this category). Then, any Social Security benefits that you might be eligible for based on wages that _were_ subject to SS tax (from another job, self-employment, etc) will be reduced by as much 85%. Requesting benefits as a _spouse_ (instead of one's own earnings) does not work either; the benefit is reduced dollar for dollar by the governmental pension.